# Вопрос по стеку в Java

Tags: java

Я вношу integer-числа в стек в нужном мне порядке. Как можно извлечь их по номеру записи?

Comment: В смысле, pop удаляет верхнюю запись, а мне нужно определенную.

Comment: Да пребудут с тобой массивы)

Comment: Да упасёт бог тебя от массивов ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимость в произвольном доступе к стеку наверняка означает изначально неверную идеологию. Это почти наверняка означает, что стэк вам на самом деле не нужен. Если нужен произвольный доступ и возможность динамически добавлять, то используйте ArrayList или LinkedList

Comment: Для произвольного доступа LinkedList не подходит.

Comment: Зато очень подходит, чтобы удалять произвольные элементы. При частых удалениях из середины ArrayList закопается на бесконечном копировании.

Answer (score 10):

Стек — **по определению** структура данных, поддерживающая только две операции: push (положить на верхушку) и pop (снять с верхушки).

Если нужно индексирование, нужна структура данных, поддерживающая индексирование ;). Например, массив.